# Struts 2 and HTML tags?

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I have a form in Struts2 as follows:

```
<s:form >
    <s:select list="#session.circleIdNameMap" label="Select Circle:"
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Circle"
        id="selectCircleDropDown" onchange="getTspList(this.value)"></s:select>
    
    <select id="selectTspDropDown"></select>
    
    <s:radio list="#{'0':'Default','1':'Latest'}" label="Select Threshold type:"
        name="flag" id="flag"></s:radio>

    <s:submit type="button" onclick="getThresholdData();return false;" />

</s:form>
```

Here I am using HTML `<select>` tag in between, due to which there is an alignment issue. The second select tag comes up. Using simple theme everything comes in a single line.

What should I do to make alignment right?

Comment: I suggest you to look at generated HTML code. Also why not to use S2 select tag?

Comment: If you're using the default "xhtml" theme there's a bunch of other HTML emitted.

Comment: @coding_idiot: As i mentioned in the question on using simple threme every form element comes in a single line which i don want

Comment: use `simple` theme and write your own CSS layouting rather than depending on struts themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `<select>` tag is used with the `<option>` tags together. See [the example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

But you could use Struts [`select` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) where the options are generated automatically from the list values.

Comment: I am populating my select tag using jQuery, so i know about html select tag. What i wanted to kow was how to fix the alignment issue which is coming due to mixing html and struts2 tag in a form. Any idea??